# Add all products in banner slide show in opencart 2x

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module

I want to add all products dynamically in homepage slider.

Without add every product:

[image: Without add every product]

I want all products display here dynamically:

[image: i want all products display here dynamically]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom module for that. It may take knowledge of coding.